# socket.io and node.js gives error on localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a development server working on 192.168.1.22 and i want to run node.js on it but it gives some error. I want to only test some cases but even can't run it. After i run it i will fetch my onclick button and from node.js sent that post to my php file. and return data from php to node.js and node.js to website.

my js :

```
var http = require('http'),  
    io = require('socket.io'),

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<h1>Sample server created with NodeJS.</h1>');
    res.end();
});
server.listen(8001);

// socket.io 
var socket = io.listen(server); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
  client.send('Hello client'); 
  client.on('message', function(){
     client.send((new Date()).getTime());
  })
});
```

My html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 8001});

    socket.connect();
    socket.on('message', function(message){
        document.getElementById('divTime').innerHTML = message;
    });     
    function GetServerTime() {
        socket.send('');
    }  
  </script>
```

Error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.22:8001/socket.io/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response socket.io.js:378
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.22:8001/socket.io/xhr-polling//1401170092339. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.22:8000' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.22:8001/socket.io/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response socket.io.js:378
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.22:8001/socket.io/xhr-polling//1401170102339. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.22:8000' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.22:8001/socket.io/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you're trying to connect to this server from another port:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.22:8000' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
```

The server code you pasted above (labeled "my js") looks fine.  I'm able to run the same code locally once I've installed the `socket.io` package.  So maybe the problem isn't starting that server code, but rather connecting to it once its started?  And if so, the error you have above points to a [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.  If you host the HTML code from within the node app, running on the same port, you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Getting same problem but not with node.js